# How to open the Maui project in Maximum Window

Tags: .net, maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows

When We run the .net MAUI Project it will open the project in minimized windows but I want to open that in the maximized window.

Where in the code I made changes so it will open in a maximized window in the Windows platform.

Answer (score 2):

Per [[HELP] How to specify a fixed size for the application window?](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/2370#discussioncomment-2630819) on Github, you can try to edit your `MauiProgram.cs` like below to open in a **maximized window** in the Windows platform when initializing the app.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;

#if WINDOWS
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Windows.Graphics;
#endif

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                  fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                  fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });
#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
            {
                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    IntPtr nativeWindowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    WindowId win32WindowsId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(nativeWindowHandle);
                    AppWindow winuiAppWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(win32WindowsId);
                    if(winuiAppWindow.Presenter is OverlappedPresenter p)
                        p.Maximize();
                    else
                    {
                        const int width = 1920;
                        const int height = 1080;
                        winuiAppWindow.MoveAndResize(new RectInt32(1920 / 2 - width / 2, 1080 / 2 - height / 2, width, height));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
#endif
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code gives me the error: "*Error CS1061 'MauiAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureLifecycleEvents' and no accessible extension method 'ConfigureLifecycleEvents' accepting a first argument of type 'MauiAppBuilder' could be found*". But that's not true, because I can directly access `builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents` outside of the conditional block. Also the conditional block's code is all grey colored, not sure what that means.

Comment: This is a better solution, because it does not require the `WinUIEx` library which is supporting only `net6.0-windows10.0.18362`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with the [WinUIEx](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx) NuGet package.

First of all, install **WinUIEx** in your project. At the moment, I guess you need to install v1.8.0 I guess.

Then add these **WINDOWS** code in MauiProgram.cs.

```cs
#if WINDOWS
using WinUIEx;
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;
#endif

namespace MauiApp1;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
            {
                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    window.Maximize();
                });
            });
        });
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: `WinUIEx` library is supported only on `net6.0-windows10.0.18362` if you are using `net7.0` then this solution will not work